# How to remove the > character when replying to email?

Tags: outlook.com

Whenever I reply to an email on Outlook.com it adds the `>` character to the beginning of every line in the previous email.

Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, that only happens when replying in **Plain Text** format, but it cannot be turned off when doing so.  If you reply to a message using **Rich Text** format, the `>` will not appear.

The first time you switch from Plain Text to Rich Text, the `>` will still be there, so just cancel your message and hit reply again.  This time it will default to Rich Text, and will not include the `>`.